# How do I add dependency javadocs in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code, javadoc

I've set up a maven project in visual studio code with the red hat java support. Everything works great, except that the intellisense doesn't include the javadoc descriptions for the functions and classes from my dependency. Is there a way to explicitly link VSCode to my library's jdocs? If so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try this:

for example, i have a project :

```
/project
 /lib
  test-1.0.0.jar
 /doc
  test-1.0.0-javadoc.jar
```

add in your `.classPath` :

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/test-1.0.0.jar">
  <attributes>
    <attribute name="javadoc_location" value="jar:platform:/resource/project/doc/test-1.0.0-javadoc.jar!/" />
  </attributes>
</classpathentry>
```