# How to show Javadoc of a imported library when hovering on its methods and classes?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, javadoc

As described in the title. We were currently using JSFML and Swing to develop a project, where I would like to view the Javadoc of JSFML in VSCode. However, when I tried to hover to show Javadoc it doesn't but throws me only a simple line.

For example: I built a `renderWindow` by using one of JSFML's package, graphic (with class `RenderWindow`), and try to hover. It shows me this:

```
org.jsfml.graphics.RenderWindow.RenderWindow(VideoMode arg0, String arg1)
```

Instead of Javadoc of it. When I went into the definition, instead of Javadoc I saw such a comment at the head of its class file:

```
 // Failed to get sources. Instead, stub sources have been generated by the disassembler.
 // Implementation of methods is unavailable.
```

How can I see the Javadoc of it in VSCode? Or I actually was not allowed to since it's restricted(?)

[Link for JSFML here if it helps:](https://jsfml.sfmlprojects.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the jar package which is downloaded from official website doesn't include the description.

Like you can see, when we hover over the function `println` and ctrl+click to see its class, the docstrings and parameter information are from the comments in class:
[image]

However, `RenderWindow.class` doesn't have this kind of comments, so java extension will only show its package structure:
[image]

It's not related to VS Code or Java extension but the `jsfml.jar` itself, you can view [JSFML javadoc](https://jsfml.sfmlprojects.org/javadoc/) to get more detailed information.

Comment: It’s common for Java that source/documentation JARs are handled separately from distribution JARs. JSFML *does* have javadoc, it’s just not included inside the distributable library, but you can download it from GitHub and associate it with the SFML library in VS Code (though I’m not sure how).

Comment: What i wanna tell you is that Javadoc hovers is provided by **Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat** and this extension will catch the comments in jar then display it when you hover the function, about you said:"download it from GitHub and associate it with the SFML library in VS Code", it‘s not achievable now, you can put a feature request in [vscode-java-pack-issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-pack/issues).

Comment: *Maybe*, but the example you’ve shown — the `PrintStream` javadoc — is actually part of the JDK, and [for JDK JARs VS Code *does* support specifying source JARs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project#_jdk-for-projects). In fact, it’s likely that the example in your screenshot makes use of that very facility, because the runtime library ships without source or Javadoc.

Comment: Anyway, you’ve linked the wrong plugin, the relevant RedHat plugin is at [redhat-developer/vscode-java](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java). And from what I can see in the issue tracker, this feature *is* already supported, e.g. in Maven projects you can add `javadoc`-classified dependencies. And this answer describes how: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56487969/1968

Comment: Thanks guys, guess I'll just view them in the online javadoc...

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph. I knew it's achievable in maven project, but op didn't mention it's about maven, so i treat it as no building tools project, and thanks for your explanation and reply about this question.

Answer (score 3):

Molly's answer explains why the javadoc is not available for your JAR.

If JSFML or any other Java dependency you use has a source jar, VS Code can use it so you can see the source and its Javadoc just like the JDK. The steps to get it visible in VS Code are:

### Steps to see Javadoc in VS Code with Attach Source

1. Get the source JAR of the dependency (e.g. download manually, using Maven, ...)
2. In VS Code, click into the class you want to see Javadoc for (e.g. `org.jsfml.graphics.RenderWindow.RenderWindow`)
3. In the file that opens with the message `Failed to get sources. Instead, stub sources have been generated by the disassembler...`, right/alt click to open the context menu and select **Attach Source**.
4. Select the source JAR that you got earlier.
5. Javadoc and source of the dependency will now be visible in VS Code and Javadoc will display on hover.

### Screenshots of steps

[Attach Source in context menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJKKd.png)

[Select source jar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Kr5v.png)

### Acknowledgement

This solution was originally proposed in https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/1855#issuecomment-823142835 on a similar issue.